# Serializing static nested class members on XStream

Tags: java, inner-classes, xstream

I have an application that uses XStream to serialize and deserialize classes to XML. It works great. I got a question whether static inner classes are serializable. Per the [XStream's FAQs](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Compatibility_enhanced_mode_advantage), it can. However, a Test class that has a nested static class doesn't seem like serializing the data.

```
    public static class TestInner
    {
        public static String param1;
        public static String param2;

        public static String getParam1()
        {
            return param1;
        }

        public static void setParam1(final String param1)
        {
            TestInner.param1 = param1;
        }

        public static String getParam2()
        {
            return param2;
        }

        public static void setParam2(final String param2)
        {
            TestInner.param2 = param2;
        }

    }


        final XStream xstream = new XStream();
        final TestInner inner = new Test.TestInner();
        inner.setParam1("valueparam1");
        inner.setParam2("valueparam2");
        logger.info("{}", xstream.toXML(inner));
```

Yields,

```
<test.Test_-TestInner/>
```

Is this a known behavior or limitation of XStream?

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms. This is a static nested class.

Answer (score 0):

Tested using [the Xstream tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html)  (which is fairly the same as the code you gave) and is working [**the difference between your code and mine is my variables are not static**] and I think that is the reason. Used the following dependency as well

```
package com.stackoverflow;
public class TestRunnerOuter {
 public static class TestRunner{
    private String name;
    public TestRunner() {}
    public TestRunner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 }
}
```

and then ->

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
TestRunner inner = new TestRunnerOuter.TestRunner();
inner.setName("Test");
System.out.println(xstream.toXML(inner));
```

dependency->

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

output ->

```
    <com.stackoverflow.TestRunnerOuter_-TestRunner>
      <name>Test</name>
    </com.stackoverflow.TestRunnerOuter_-TestRunner>
```

Comment: Normal examples work whereas static members aren't handled here.